# How to add a custom serializer to Djoser token field when using Simple JWT?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, djoser

In the Djoser docs they show you how to add custom serializers to various fields including token and token_create ([djoser docs](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#serializers)) however I can't seem to be able to add a custom serializer for the token field when using Simple JWT.

Answer (score 1):

I ended just removing djoser.urls.jwt from my urls and adding simple jwt urls directly and in there I added my custom view and serializer. [Simple JWT Docs](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing_token_claims.html#customizing-token-claims)

```
path('auth/jwt/create/', MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view(),
     name='token_obtain_pair'),
```

Is there a better solution?